# Default tick settings d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axis

Is it possible to call d3.svg.axis() attributes and (if nothing is returned) still have D3 set the defaults?  For example, if I have  tick values, then set them, otherwise don't:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0,440]).domain([0,10])
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 400)
var ticks = [1,8]
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .tickValues(function() {
        if(typeof(ticks=='object')) {return ticks}
        else {return this}
        // also tried:
        else {return}
        else {}
    })
```

It would be great to invoke the .tickValues() function, but if in cases where I don't have a ticks object, have D3 set the defaults. Here is a js fiddle to test out solutions: http://jsfiddle.net/sWQUu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass in `null` to the tickValues function -- you'll get the default behaviour.

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .tickValues(
       ( (typeof ticks) == 'object') ? 
            ticks : 
            null
    );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sWQUu/2/

However, this doesn't seem to work if you give a function as a parameter to `.tickValues`, and the function returns null:

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .tickValues( function() {
       return ( (typeof ticks) == 'object') ? 
            ticks : 
            null //causes an error
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sWQUu/3/

If you need to use a function because you want the check for explicit tick values to happen each time the axis is called, you can grab the default tick values from the scale:

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .tickValues(function() {
       return ( (typeof ticks) == 'object') ? 
            ticks : 
            x.ticks()
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sWQUu/4/

Or, to be more flexible:

```
var axis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(5)
    .tickValues(function() {
       return ( (typeof ticks) == 'object') ? 
            ticks : 
            x.ticks.apply(x, axis.ticks() );
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sWQUu/5/

The call to `axis.ticks()` grabs any tick-related arguments that have been specified on the axis, in this case the number 5, and passes them on as arguments to the scale's `.ticks()` method.  You have to use `function.apply` to make it work because `axis.ticks()` returns an array of arguments, not just a single value (to allow for datetime scales that take multiple arguments when specifying what sort of ticks you want).

The only catch is that I'm referencing the scale and axis by variable name, not by their association with the axis object, so if you change the meaning of `x` or `axis` within this function, the new values will be used not the values associated with this particular axis functions.  (You can't reference them as `this` for the axis and `this.scale()` for the scale because the internal workings of d3 means that this function is getting called with a d3 selection of the `<g>` element as the `this` context.)  I can't think of a situation where that would likely be a problem, but something to be aware of anyway.